# How do you move the image that the user imports using uiimagepicker all the way to the right of the ui image view?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm currently trying to use uiimagepicker to import a user image, but I want the uiimage inside of the uiimageview to be all the way to the right inside the uiimageview while preserving the aspect ratio and size of the imported photo. Right now it's just showing up in the middle.

[Where i want the image to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUEsw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

UIImage holds image data needed to display on the screen but not the location of the image on the screen. To move your image around, you need to change the location of the UIImageView instead.

Comment: I can’t do that because if someone imports an image that isn’t cropped, the image would not have to move, but if it is cropped then it has to move, so this is not possible